# How do I rearrange XML nodes in PHP with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'd like to rearrange elements in the file, I do not want to use another attribute for element ordering/arrangement.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be better to use the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension for this rather than SimpleXML. SimpleXML as far as I know does not allow you to save changes back to a file easily (at least without using DOM anyway).

Once you have a reference to the DOMNode you want to move you can first remove it:

```
$node = $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

Then put it before a different node:

```
$node = $otherNode->insertBefore($node);
```

This probably isn't a detailed enough answer - please can you add some more information about exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to rearrange (move them up or down, or to a specific order) nodes in one level. But your answer already solved my problem, lots of thanks! :D